# Typescript type that's like record but creates union types

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type alias for following code:

```js
type Foo = {alpha: string} | {beta: string}
```

I want to create a type that creates this as follows where I define the type above as `Foo<'alpha' | 'beta', string>`

```js
type Foo<K, T> = ...
```

Record is not an option since following is true:

```js
Record<'alpha' | 'beta', string> === {
    alpha: string;
    beta: string;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types). Consider below code:

```
type GenericFoo<KeyT extends PropertyKey, ValueT> = {
  [Key in KeyT]: { [Key2 in Key]: ValueT }
}[KeyT];

type Foo = GenericFoo<'alpha' | 'beta', string>
```

`Foo` is evaluated as an union:

```
type Foo = {
    alpha: string;
} | {
    beta: string;
}
```

Some explanation:

- `GenericFoo` creates a mapped type with values representing all pairs of `{key,value}`
- `[KeyT]` at the end of `GenericFoo` definition means we take all value types of the mapped type, it means we get the union of all `{key,value}` pairs.

Comment: Maybe this was not supported at the time this question was asked, but is the proposed solution equivalent to `type Foo = Partial<Record<'alpha' | 'beta', string>>`  now?

Comment: @alexandroid not quite though it may be close enough depending on the use case. The type you suggest has both keys but each may be undefined, where the type in the answer may have either key (or both) but if the key is present, its value is not undefined.